# google app engine Backups stuck in pending state

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, backup

My google app engine daily datastore backups were working fine, but from 7th October, all of them are stuck in pending state with elapsed time 0, no changes has been done to configurations.

The manual backups are ending up in similar pending state.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its hard to reveal the problem without full access/info, probably you should try to ask support to help you